# Algum motivo pro removeClass() não funcionar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Vejam só, tudo esta funcionando como esperado, menos o removeClass no final do script. Ele simplesmente se recusa a remover a class. Tem algo errado?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cheight = $(".categorias > ul").height();
  $(".categorias > ul").css("height", cheight);

  var formheight = $(".menulateral form").height();
  $(".subcategorias").css("top", -formheight)

  $(document).on('click', '.categorias > ul > li', function() {
    $(".menulateral form").addClass("ocultarform");
    $(this).children(".subcategorias").addClass('subcategoriasactive');
    var subheight = $(this).children(".subcategorias").height();
    $(".categorias > ul").css("height", subheight - formheight);
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.subtitle', function() {
    $(".subcategorias").removeClass("subcategoriasactive");
  });

});
```

```css
.categorias {
  position: relative;
}

.categorias li {
  list-style: none;
}

.categorias a {
  color: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.categorias ul>li>a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 19px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.05);
}

.categorias ul>li>a svg {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.subcategorias {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #444;
  z-index: 5;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  display: inline-table;
  width: 100%;
}

.subcategoriasactive {
  right: 0;
}

.subcategorias .subtitle {
  background: #333;
}

.ocultarform {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='categorias'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>
        <span>CAMISETAS</span>
      </a>
      <ul class='subcategorias'>
        <li class='subtitle'>
          <a>
            <span>CAMISETAS</span>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="">FILMES</a></li>
        <li><a href="">SÉRIES</a></li>
        <li><a href="">MEMES</a></li>
        <li><a href="">FRASES</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a>
        <span>CANECAS</span>
      </a>
      <ul class='subcategorias'>
        <li><a href="">ALGUMA</a></li>
        <li><a href="">COISA</a></li>
        <li><a href="">MEMES</a></li>
        <li><a href="">FRASES</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li style='position:relative;'>
      <a>
        <span style='margin-left:29px;'>CHINELOS</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Aparentemente não. Consegue fazer um [mcve] demonstrando o que está tentando fazer?

Comment: Olha no link. https://jsfiddle.net/14rt82no/1/

Comment: Se clicar em Camisetas no primeiro menu ele vai adicionar a class pra ativar o submenu, e quando clicar no primeiro item do submenu, que por sua vez, também é "Camisetas", é onde o removeClass() é disparado. Mas nada acontece.

Comment: Acontece sim. A classe é removida como deveria, porém esse `<li>` está dentro do primeiro `<li>` CAMISETAS, que abre o menu; quando você clica no interno, o evento de clique é propagado pelos elementos pais (*bubbling*) e acaba disparando novamente a função que adiciona a classe. Como é executado muito rápido nem é perceptível essa alteração visualmente.

Comment: Certo. Sou novo nisso, vou tentar resolver. Valeu

Answer (score 0):

O removeClass está funcionando corretamente. O problema é de que depois que o evento clique do subtitle ocorre, o outro evento de chique com esse seletor '.categorias > ul > li' é chamado novamente pois também foi clicado, e acaba por adicionar novamente a classe.

Utilize o script a seguir:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cheight = $(".categorias > ul").height();
  $(".categorias > ul").css("height", cheight);

  var formheight = $(".menulateral form").height();
  $(".subcategorias").css("top", -formheight)

  $(document).on('click', '.categorias > ul > li', function() {
    $(".menulateral form").addClass("ocultarform");
    if(!$(".subcategorias").hasClass("subcategoriasactive"))
        $(this).children(".subcategorias").addClass('subcategoriasactive');
    else
        $(this).children(".subcategorias").removeClass('subcategoriasactive');
    var subheight = $(this).children(".subcategorias").height();
    $(".categorias > ul").css("height", subheight - formheight);
  });

});
```

```css
.categorias {
  position: relative;
}

.categorias li {
  list-style: none;
}

.categorias a {
  color: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.categorias ul>li>a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 19px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.05);
}

.categorias ul>li>a svg {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.subcategorias {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #444;
  z-index: 5;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  display: inline-table;
  width: 100%;
}

.subcategoriasactive {
  right: 0;
}

.subcategorias .subtitle {
  background: #333;
}

.ocultarform {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='categorias'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>
        <span>CAMISETAS</span>
      </a>
      <ul class='subcategorias'>
        <li class='subtitle'>
          <a>
            <span>CAMISETAS</span>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="">FILMES</a></li>
        <li><a href="">SÉRIES</a></li>
        <li><a href="">MEMES</a></li>
        <li><a href="">FRASES</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a>
        <span>CANECAS</span>
      </a>
      <ul class='subcategorias'>
        <li><a href="">ALGUMA</a></li>
        <li><a href="">COISA</a></li>
        <li><a href="">MEMES</a></li>
        <li><a href="">FRASES</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li style='position:relative;'>
      <a>
        <span style='margin-left:29px;'>CHINELOS</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ao invés de fazer um `if` para adicionar a classe se não possuir, ou remover em caso contrário, você pode usar a função `toggleClass` que já faz isso para você.

Comment: Tem toda razão Anderson, obrigado!